# Issue Tracking Widget Suggestion

Tags: issue-tracking

Can you suggest a very very simple issue tracking widget.  UserVoice, is a little too involved for us with their forums and what not.  What we want is something that just allows people to send us an issue or note and grabs a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hava a look at [userrules.com](http://www.userrules.com)

It allows you to integrate to your internal Issue Tracking system (JIRA, BugZilla, Redmine, Basecamp etc.). Any feedback from your customers come, you can directly export it to ur external system. And it will keep track of its progress for you.

Liked, what they have done with their UI, plus you can add your own customizable fields to ask some specific info from your customers in the feedback widget.

Answer (score 3):

If by widget you mean something that you can embed on your page that will allow visitors to leave feedback/issues, there are javascript plugins, like [feedback_me](https://github.com/vedmack/feedback_me) that will allow posting feedback to a backend provided by you.

If your are not comfortable with supplying a backend of your own, there are of course countless products that will do basic stuff for you and more. This is list by no means complete, but it's a start:

- [Usersnap](https://usersnap.com)
- [Trackduck](https://trackduck.com)
- [Marker](https://getmarker.io)
- [Userback](https://userback.io)
- [Bugmuncher](https://www.bugmuncher.com)
- [Doorbell](https://doorbell.io)

Answer (score 0):

Getsatisfaction? BitBucket? Github? Google Code? All have issue trackers and, except for that last one, allow you to keep your code private, but your issues public.